# MVC Attributes on abstract properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an abstract Model

```
public abstract class Treasure {
    public abstract int Value { get; }
    public abstract string Label { get; }
}
```

and an implementation

```
public class Coins : Treasure {
    [DisplayName("Coin Value")]
    public override int Value {
        get { ... }
    }

    [DisplayName("Coins")]
    public override string Label {
        get { ... }
    }
```

My coins object does not show "Coins" as its label in my view when I use `Html.LabelFor` on it, it shows "Label". If I move the DisplayName attribute into Treasure, it works... but I need to be able to change the label for different implementations of the Treasure class. Is this possible?

Comment: And what is the model in the view... Treasure or Coins?

Comment: Have you tried implementing a default value on the Treasure object and on the Coins object? just a thought.

Comment: Just to be clear, it would be good to see the snippet of Razor markup which contains "LabelFor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work fine if the model in the view is Coins.  However if the model is Treasure, it fails.  Why?  Because when the Html Helper renders the Html it only looks at the model type that is specified in the view, not the object type of the actual object.  When it goes to get the attribute it will only get the attribute for Treasure and not Coins.  I think you would have to write your own Html helper for this.

```
internal static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
{
  return LabelExtensions.LabelHelper((HtmlHelper) html, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData, metadataProvider), ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression) expression), labelText, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Under the covers, MVC uses `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>` to find the "DisplayName" and when it fails to find one on the type passed in... it returns the `PropertyName`.

```
internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, string labelText = null, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
  string str = labelText;
  if (str == null)
  {
    string displayName = metadata.DisplayName;
    if (displayName == null)
    {
      string propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
      if (propertyName == null)
        str = Enumerable.Last<string>((IEnumerable<string>) htmlFieldName.Split(new char[1]
        {
          '.'
        }));
      else
        str = propertyName;
    }
    else
      str = displayName;
  }
  string innerText = str;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
  TagBuilder tagBuilder1 = new TagBuilder("label");
  tagBuilder1.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
  tagBuilder1.SetInnerText(innerText);
  TagBuilder tagBuilder2 = tagBuilder1;
  bool flag = true;
  IDictionary<string, object> attributes = htmlAttributes;
  int num = flag ? 1 : 0;
  tagBuilder2.MergeAttributes<string, object>(attributes, num != 0);
  return TagBuilderExtensions.ToMvcHtmlString(tagBuilder1, TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Comment: Good explanation with code. Indeed it looks at `@model` declaration not the actual type.